# Running multiple node express applications on single port

Tags: node.js, express

I am want to make proxy manger application for express,
but I have error all time that I try to do  require for two diffrent applications.
i am using on `app.use` to route between the two application.
thanks alot 
david

```
var app1 = require('./../app1/server/server');
var app2 = require('./../app2/server/server');
var app = require('express')();

app.use("/", app1);
app.use("/app2", app2);

app.listen(80, console.log("server up"))
```

Error is :

> event,js:85 listen eaddrinuse

Comment: Please add the relevant code and the error.

Comment: Edit your question with the code

Comment: So you should have the same port listening in the server.js files, change them or post that files too.

Comment: the erorr not coming from the app.listen is come from the require of  the two apps ...

Comment: Indeed I told you to check the server.js files this `./../app1/server/server`and this `./../app2/server/server`

Comment: is need to be posibol to do app.use on other app ?

Comment: If you're listening to port 80 and it fails it might be that it's used by sth like apache or nginx running on your system. Did you try using sth like port 3000?

Comment: have you researched NodeJS Cluster facility? The error your seeing is because that address that the 2nd server is trying to "bind" to is already in use by app1.

Comment: the bug is fixed i have some other application in my app thats listen twice to port 9000 thanks

Answer (score 0):

The port 80 is in use by another process. try with another empty port like 8080 or 3000. You can also try by stopping the application that is using port 80, then it will work.